# Не могу разобраться с jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json

```
Json::Value root;   // will contains the root value after parsing.
Json::Reader reader;
bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( config_doc, root );
```

Насколько я понимаю, должно было построиться абстрактное синтаксическое дерево с корнем в root.
Но непонятно, откуда например взять список детей root..

Answer (score 2):

Это текст, который будем парсить.

```
{
    "database":
    {
        "ip":"127.0.0.1",
        "name":"base",
        "user":"userbase",
        "pass":"1111"
    },

    "log":
    {
        "dir":"logs",
        "remote":"/var/www/html/base/logs/"
    }
}
```

А это код, который парсит этот текст.

```
Json::Reader reader;
Json::Value value = Json::arrayValue;
std::string text="{\"database\":{\"ip\":\"127.0.0.1\",\"name\":\"base\",\"user\":\"userbase\",\"pass\":\"1111\"},\"log\":{\"dir\":\"logs\",\"remote\":\"/var/www/html/base/logs/\"}}";

if(!reader.parse(text, value))return false;

std::string ip_db = value["database"]["ip"].asString();
std::string name_db = value["database"]["name"].asString();
std::string user_db = value["database"]["user"].asString();
std::string pass_db = value["database"]["pass"].asString();
std::string dir_log = value["log"]["dir"].asString();
std::string dir_log_remote = value["log"]["remote"].asString();
```

Если Вы не знаете наименований ключей, то их можно узнать следующим образом:

```
Json::Value::Members members = value.getMemberNames();

for(size_t i=0; i<members.size(); i++)
    std::cout << members[i] << std::endl;

Json::Value value_child = value[members[0]];

Json::Value::Members members_child = value_child.getMemberNames();
for(size_t i=0; i<members_child.size(); i++)
    std::cout << members_child[i] << std::endl;
```

Если массив не ассоциативный, то перебрать его значения можно вот так:

```
for(size_t i=0; i<value.size(); i++)
        std::cout << value[i] << std::endl;
```

Определить какой это массив (ассоциативный или нет) можно такими проверками:

```
if(value.isObject()) std::cout << "Ассоциативный";
if(value.isArray()) std::cout << "Обычный";
```

Проверить корректность json можно вот [здесь](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать итераторы:

```
Json::Value root;
Json::Reader reader;

if ( reader.parse(json, root, false) ) {
    Json::ValueIterator it;
    for(it = root.begin(); it != root.end(); ++it) {
        std::string key = it.key().asString();
        std::string value = it.asString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы проверяли код, который написали ? Через итератор действительно можно выдернуть ключ ?